# cc1 custom editor in editemplate

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I am trying to use customized editor in edittemplate of the form. For whatever reason it doesn't show the data bound to the field and nor does it allow me to enter any text in it. I have VS2012(asp.net) with sqlserver 2008r2.

This is what I have in my field looks like in the edit template.

```
<custom:CustomEditor runat="server" ID="txtBanNotes" Content='<%# Bind("BannedInfo") %>' Width="37em" Height="10em" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Enabled="true" />
```

Not sure what else I need or how to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled the Ajax tool kit and it is working ok now.